# Convert GMT+0000 Timestamp to proper time

Tags: javascript, timestamp, utc

How do i get javascript to return the correct time format. In the code below the result of text2 shows up as 9:45:00 AM instead of 1:45:00 PM which is the correct time selected user selected in firebase. I need just the time

```
const d = new Date("Fri Oct 28 2022 13:45:00 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)");
let text = d.toUTCString();
let text2 = d.toLocaleTimeString();
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text2;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your `GMT + X` gaps to your calculation, by using the [`new Date().getTimezoneOffset()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset)

```js
let d = new Date("Fri Oct 28 2022 13:45:00 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)");
d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes() + new Date().getTimezoneOffset())
let text = d.toUTCString();
let text2 = d.toLocaleTimeString();
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text2;
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: it works fine in javascript but doesn't in node.js what could be the problem?

Comment: for some reason it didn't work in Node.js